# Difference between FOR UPDATE OF and FOR UPDATE

Tags: oracle, locking, sql-update

What makes difference, when I use `FOR UPDATE OF SAL` or simply write `FOR UPDATE`.

According to [O'Reilly](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/prog2/ch06_11.htm)

> The OF list of the FOR UPDATE clause does not restrict you to changing
>   only those columns listed. Locks are still placed on all rows; the OF
>   list just gives you a way to document more clearly what you intend to
>   change. If you simply state FOR UPDATE in the query and do not include
>   one or more columns after the OF keyword, then the database will then
>   lock all identified rows across all tables listed in the FROM clause.

Which means, when I specify column name with `FOR UPDATE OF SAL`, other user can make change with `SAL` column only. But, practically, this is not the case. I'm still getting lock in other session. Can anyone explain the difference.

**UPDATE**

```
 ----- SESSION 1

declare
 emp_info emp.ename%type;
 cursor emp_cur is select ename from emp join dept using(deptno) where deptno=&no for update of sal;
 begin
 open emp_cur;
 loop
 fetch emp_cur into emp_info;
 exit when emp_cur%notfound;
 dbms_output.put_line(emp_info);
 end loop;
 close emp_cur;
 end;

  ----- SESSION 2

  update emp set comm=5 where deptno=10;
  ---- hanged/waiting in session 2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55372):

> Use the `OF ...` column clause to lock the select rows only for a
>   particular table or view in a join. The columns in the `OF` clause only
>   indicate which table or view rows are locked. The specific columns
>   that you specify are not significant. However, you must specify an
>   actual column name, not a column alias. If you omit this clause, then
>   the database locks the selected rows from all the tables in the query.

If your query references a single table then there is no difference between `FOR UPDATE` and `FOR UPDATE OF ...`, but the latter may still be useful as self-documentation to indicate which columns you intend to update. It doesn't restrict what you can update though. If you have:

```
CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM emp FOR UPDATE OF sal;
```

then you can still do:

```
UPDATE emp SET comm = comm * 1.1 WHERE CURRENT OF cur;
```

But if there is more than one table then `FOR UPDATE OF ...` will only lock the rows in the tables that contain the columns you specify in the `OF` clause.

Contrary to what I think you're saying in the question. specifying `FOR UPDATE OF sal` does not only lock the `sal` column; you can never lock a single column, the minimum lock is at row level. ([Read more about locks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#i5704)). It locks all rows in the table that contains the `SAL` column, which are selected by the query.

---

In the update to your question, your cursor query is joining `emp` and `dept`, but the `OF` clause only has `sal`, a column in the `emp` table. The rows in the `emp` table will be locked when the cursor is opened, and those locks won't be released until you `commit` or `rollback` that session. Within your cursor loop you can do:

```
UPDATE emp SET ... WHERE CURRENT OF emp_cur;
```

... to update the row in the `emp` table that relates to this iteration of the loop. You *cannot* do:

```
UPDATE dept SET ... WHERE CURRENT OF emp_cur;
```

... because rows in the `dept` table are not locked, because no columns were in the `OF`. That also means that in your second session the `dept` rows can be updated freely, as they are not locked by the first session.

Comment: No, what i meant to say is that, it will let me update when i'll try to update other column. Even, i join two table, but still same scenario. Please check my updated post and please explain.

Comment: @jWeavers - you shouldn't be able to update a column in a table if that table has no references in the `OF` clause. Using `WHERE CURRENT OF`, anyway - there's nothing stopping you updating anything you like with a normal `UPDATE` without that clause - including in tables you've locked with `FOR UPDATE`, since you hold that lock.

Comment: @jWeavers - from your update: right, you've locked the **row** in `emp`, so the second session has to wait for the first session to release the locks (`commit`/`rollback`), even though no updates were made. Your second session can still update `dept` though, as no columns from that table were in the `OF` clause.

Comment: So, If I will specify `deptno` with `OF` clause, then, it will lock associative rows of `dept` table. Isn't ? Other than that, both behavior are same.

Comment: @jWeavers - `deptno` is in both tables, so you'd need to include `dept.deptno`; in that case yes, it would lock the rows in `dept` too. If you have `FOR UPDATE OF emp.sal, dept.deptno` then you're locking the rows in both tables, which would happen with a simple `FOR UPDATE` as well, without the `OF` clause.

Comment: So you can't do column level locks (only row level locks), so I have to create a separate table to autonomously add log columns for any processing?

Comment: @Superdooperhero - not sure what you mean. If you're processing data in a row (i.e. updating it) then that whole row is locked, so something like a last-updated column can be updated at the same time. You might need to ask a new question to explain what you are trying to do and what issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

one additional comment on for update.  If you select from multiple tables and don't have where clause for referencing each table for the update then it will lock all of the tables until the update is done.