# Oracle FOR UPDATE (OF) Cursor behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, cursor

We have a script for update of a specific column. In this script we are using a `FOR UPDATE`cursor. In the first version of the script we did not use the `OF`part of the `FOR UPDATE`clause. As we found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081582/difference-between-for-update-of-and-for-update) and [here](http://www.fast-track.cc/___aaa_pl_sql_cursor_for_update.htm) this should not affect the script as all rows of all joined tables should be locked and therefore can be updated.

But when we were running the script although the log messages were printed no update was made on the column (column_a).

When we were changing the script with the cursor having an `FOR UPDATE OF t1.column_a`the same log messages appear but the updates are made correctly!

Can anyone explain why the script does not work without the `OF`clause?

The Oracle database version is 'Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0' also tested with 'Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit'.

Here's a simple version of the executed script:

```
    BEGIN
      -- anonymous procedure
      DECLARE PROCEDURE update_column_a IS
        c_to_find CONSTANT NUMBER := -42;
        c_constant_value CONSTANT VARCHAR2 := 'value';
        CURSOR c_my_cursor IS
          SELECT t1.* 
            FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3
           WHERE t1.t2_id = t2.id
             AND t2.t3_id = t3.id
             AND t3.column_b = c_to_find
             -- FOR UPDATE with OF clause works
             -- FOR UPDATE OF t1.column_a;

             -- FOR UPDATE without OF clause does not
             FOR UPDATE;
      BEGIN
        FOR cursor_rec IN c_my_cursor LOOP
          IF cursor_rec.column_a IS NULL OR cursor_rec.column_a = '' THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('Updating column...');
            UPDATE t1 SET column_a = c_constant_value WHERE CURRENT OF   c_my_cursor;
          ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('Column already set...');
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END update_column_a;
      -- anonymous execution
      BEGIN
        update_column_a;
      END;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Oracle 11G PL/SQL documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS602):

> When SELECT FOR UPDATE queries multiple tables, it locks only rows
>   whose columns appear in the FOR UPDATE clause.

So it might appear that in your example, no rows are locked and `current of` might not work.

However, when I try this:

```
declare
  cursor c is
    select ename, dname
      from emp join dept on dept.deptno = emp.deptno
      for update;
begin
  for r in c loop
     null;
  end loop;
end;
```

I find that the rows of EMP and DEPT **are** locked (an update to either from another session hangs).

If I change the code to try to update one of the tables, it works fine for EMP:

```
declare
  cursor c is
    select ename, dname
      from emp join dept on dept.deptno = emp.deptno
      for update;
begin
  for r in c loop
     update emp
       set ename = upper(ename)
      where current of c;
  end loop;
end;
```

But if I try to update DEPT instead I get the exception:

> ORA-01410: invalid ROWID

This doesn't surprise me, because I have a foreign key from EMP to DEPT, and EMP will be "key-preserved" by the cursor's query, but DEPT will not be (i.e the same DEPT row can appear more than once in the results).

This suggests to me that the documentation is wrong, or at least misleading.  However, I cannot see how your code could just not update the row, without raising an error as mine did.

Comment: As I understand the documentation, this reduces the lock to the tables with the specified columns. According to that [website](http://www.fast-track.cc/___aaa_pl_sql_cursor_for_update.htm) all rows should be locked. 'If the cursor will join tables, then all the rows returned by the cursor in both tables are locked.'

Comment: We did not get any exception. This makes it some kind of confusing to us too as it simply does not update the columns.

Comment: I wouldn't trust anything Don Burleson publishes as a rule, but he seems to be right there!

Comment: FWIW I still get the `ORA-01410: invalid ROWID` exception even if I specify `for update of dname`, and whether the foreign key exists or not.

Comment: I found [this forum answer](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2245826?tstart=0) that says "You cannot use the CURRENT OF clause with a cursor declared with a join* since internally, the CURRENT OF mechanism uses the ROWID pseudocolumn and there is no way to specify which table the ROWID relates to".  That makes sense, and accounts for my ORA-01410 - but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be stated in the PL/SQL documentation (and of course, the update of EMP **did** work for me!)

Comment: The last part of the answer describes the problem. The rowid is unambiguous. Found this [post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:18785800825319) of Tom Kyte which makes it somewhat clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

"Can anyone explain why the script does not work without the OFclause?"

You are almost there :)

What does the FOR UPDATE in regular? --> locks the result set

```
          SELECT t1.* 
            FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3
           WHERE t1.t2_id = t2.id
             AND t2.t3_id = t3.id
             AND t3.column_b = c_to_find
             FOR UPDATE;
```

So, in that way you cannot UPDATE none of these tables in the resultset.

But, if you specify the FOR UPDATE OF clause, then you're telling to ORACLE you want make an exception in the lock, naming the specific column.

```
      SELECT t1.* 
        FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3
       WHERE t1.t2_id = t2.id
         AND t2.t3_id = t3.id
         AND t3.column_b = c_to_find
         FOR UPDATE OF t1.column_a;
```

Comment: I don't think so. As I understand the documentation the OF clause is used to have a more precised lock which should be more performant. FOR UPDATE without OF should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across below lines in one of the books.

You can use the FOR UPDATE clause in a SELECT against multiple tables. In this case,rows in a table are locked only if the FOR UPDATE clause references a column in that table. In the following example, the FOR UPDATE clause does not result in any locked rows in the winterize table:

```
 CURSOR fall_jobs_cur IS
 SELECT w.task, w.expected_hours,
        w.tools_required,
        w.do_it_yourself_flag
   FROM winterize w, husband_config hc
  WHERE w.year_of_task = TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
    AND w.task_id = hc.task_id
    FOR UPDATE OF hc.max_procrastination_allowed;
```

Comment: We already clarified that. FOR UPDATE without the OF clause does lock any table in the FROM clause. If you would have tested it, you could have seen it...